# Append childnode(s) base on parentnode's attribute in generating XML

Tags: c#, xml, append

Here are the codes.

```
<P type="DOC-2012-001">
    <V n="ID">0</V>
    <V n="TYPE">Page</V>
    <V n="STATUS">0</V>
    <V n="IMAGEFILE"></V>
    <V n="DATAFILE"></V>
    <V n="TEMPLATE IMAGE"></V>
    <V n="MIN_TYPES">0</V>
    <V n="MAX_TYPES">0</V>
    <V n="rules"></V>
    <F type="Remark1" pos="0" min="0" max="0"/>
    <F type="Remark2" pos="0" min="0" max="0"/>
</P>
<F type="Remark1">
    <V n="ID">0</V>
    <V n="TYPE">Field</V>
    <V n="STATUS">0</V>
    <V n="POSITION">0,0,0,0</V>
    <V n="MIN_TYPES">0</V>
    <V n="MAX_TYPES">0</V>
    <V n="ReqConf">8</V>
    <V n="rules">&lt;in&gt;&lt;r id=&quot;1&quot; rs=&quot;9&quot; /&gt;&lt;/in&gt;</V>
</F>
```

i wish to add `<F>` into one of the `<P type=>` and there are a list of `<P>` and a list of `<F>` which are separated but referenced by same "type".

Comment: If you want to know more, tell us more. What technology (`XmlDocument` or `XDocument`, or not DOM at all?) are you using, what have you tried, ...?

Comment: Your example is not a valid XML.

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev: But it's a valid HTML though :)

Comment: @abatishchev X1 is not a valid HTML tag then ;o) Also, `p` tag has no `type` attribute.

Comment: Sorry guys i am generating xml

Comment: @abatishchev Nesting paragraphs isn't allowed if you ask W3Cs validator though, however valid it may be with closing tags :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument("file.xml");
var pTypeOne = doc.Descendants("P").Single(e => e.Attribute("type").Value == "1");
pTypeOne.Add(new XElement("X1"));
```

Comment: I hope you'll not mind my edit, one-linear looks better for me, hope for you too :)

Comment: @abatishchev I actually like it, looks simpler in this case :)

Comment: By hand (remember closing your tags) it would be 
    <P type="1">
        <X1 />
    </P>
    <P type="2" />